# List comprehension example I don't understand

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, list-comprehension

I'm having trouble understanding a particular list comprehension example. In the sample code below a list comprehension is used for the parameter of the set method. Most examples I've seen usually look like this "x for x in y". I've read documentation but it isn't clearing it up for me. What exactly is [marks for name] doing. Shouldn't it be [marks for marks]?

```
marksheet = []
for _ in range(0,int(input())):
    marksheet.append([input(), float(input())])

second_highest = sorted(list(set([marks for name, marks in marksheet])))[1]
print('\n'.join([a for a,b in sorted(marksheet) if b == second_highest]))
```

Comment: You'll want to lookup list comprehensions to understand the first line, and the documentation of `join` for the second.

Comment: it's also overcomplex. `sorted(list(set([marks for name, marks in marksheet])))[1]` => `sorted({marks for name, marks in marksheet})[1]`

Comment: I've looked up list comprehension but I still don't understand. I only see the iterative part of of the list comprehension but not transform or filter hence I do not understand the expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is using Python's list comprehension to create a list from another list based on the condition.

See more about list comprehensions here:
https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/list-comprehension

The `[1]` is accessing the item at index 1 (2nd item) of your sorted list.

As for `.join`, each line in the sorted list is being printed out with a newline (`\n`) between each one.

Comment: Okay the [1] is doing just as I speculated and I only needed to look at a bit of documentation to see what .join does.  Sorry for asking again but after reading I still couldn't fully grasp list comprehension. I think I don't understand the expression but you do. Could you explain this expression?   "marks for name"

Comment: It looks like marksheet is a list of lists with 2 items in each of the inner lists. e.g: `marksheets = [[a,b],[c,d],[e,f]...]`
So, what that is doing is putting item 2 of the inner lists `marks` into a new list. For every item `marks` in marksheet `[name, marks] in marksheet`, it is putting the second item `marks` into a new list.

Comment: A list comprehension is a way to loop through one list and create another at the same time. You can do the same like thing like this: 
`my_list = [[['a','b'],['c','d'],['e','f']]  
new_list = []  
for x, y in my_list:  
    new_list.append(y)  
print new_list  
['b', 'd', 'f']`